# How to read Fitbit Activity/Sleep detailed data for specified date range?

Tags: c#, fitbit

I was wondering if there was anyway to get a date range of data from Fitbit, such as the detailed Activity and detailed sleep data as we get for one single day. The application I am working on may need to grab data for a long time period for a user. Is there anything in the Fitbit API where I could grab this information for a range of days in just one query to the server?

Answer (score 1):

**Later edit: as far as i know you cannot grab all resources for a specified date range.**

I think you're searching for Activity Time Series.

You can retrieve activity time series filtered for a specified date range, but you can find them only by resource-path.

There are two acceptable formats for retrieving activity time series data:

```
GET /1/user/[user-id]/[resource-path]/date/[date]/[period].json

GET /1/user/[user-id]/[resource-path]/date/[base-date]/[end-date].json
```

Resource Path Options are the following:

- activities/calories
- activities/caloriesBMR
- activities/steps
- activities/distance
- activities/floors
- activities/elevation
- activities/minutesSedentary
- activities/minutesLightlyActive
- activities/minutesFairlyActive
- activities/minutesVeryActive
- activities/activityCalories

And you have the same for sleep, Sleep Time Series.

```
GET https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/[resource-path]/date/[date]/[period].json

GET https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/[resource-path]/date/[base-date]/[end-date].json
```

Resource path options are the following:

- sleep/startTime
- sleep/timeInBed
- sleep/minutesAsleep
- sleep/awakeningsCount
- sleep/minutesAwake
- sleep/minutesToFallAsleep
- sleep/minutesAfterWakeup
- sleep/efficiency

Example request:

```
GET https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/28H22H/sleep/minutesAsleep/date/2014-09-01/today.json
```

It will give you the minutesAsleep between 2014-09-01 and today.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.I did find this in Fitbit API docs but all these URL will return me the data for type of activity specified in Resource-path parameter. What if I want to get detailed Activity(eg: steps,Calories,Distance,Elevation etc.) for date range in a single url hit. Is there anyway I can achieve this? Please let me know if not clear. Thanks again :)

Comment: I wasn't able to find any call that will get all activities, all sleep data, just per resource. Probably this is how they designed the API and an endpoint for getting all activities, all sleep data for a period won't be available in the future.